# How can I show Laravel FullCalendar of Next Month

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, fullcalendar

I've to show Default Next Month in Maddhatter/FullCalendar in Laravel

I've tried by putting following code in my Controller:

```
$calendar_details = Calendar::addEvents($event_list, [
     'color' => '#daf2ff',
])->setOptions([
            'next'
        ]);
```

But Nothing happens. Please Help Me!

Comment: `next` is not an option in fullCalendar. Even if it was, you didn't set a value for it...what kind of option has no value? What you've written makes no sense. There is a button called "next" which you can display, but you set that via the header options, as per Prafulla's answer. (and the fullCalendar docs and code samples would tell you that, if you read them)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved by adding following line of code:

```
'defaultDate'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime("+1 month"))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `header` option like below code and that should display `prev` and `next` options.

```
$calendar = \Calendar::addEvents($events)
            ->setOptions([
                'defaultView' => 'listDay',
                'header' =>
                    [
                        'left' => 'prev,next today',
                        'center' => 'title',
                        'right' => 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listDay',
                    ]
            ])
```

In JS there is an option to [go to](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/gotoDate) a specific month, in this package, I do not think so as the [Calendar](https://github.com/maddhatter/laravel-fullcalendar/blob/master/src/MaddHatter/LaravelFullcalendar/Calendar.php) class do not have any such methods.

```
.fullCalendar( ‘gotoDate’, date )
```

Comment: Yes, I can manipulate dates with Prev & Next Button. But, I want to always show Calendar of Next Month.

Comment: @DipenChand "But, I want to always show Calendar of Next Month" ...when you click the "next" button, then, assuming you're in "month" view, it will always change to show the next month. If you're in "week" view, then (logically) it will go to the next week. If that's not what you mean, then you'll have to give us a clearer statement of your requirement.